# Convert a key:value file w/ comments into JSON document with UNIX tools

Tags: bash, shell, awk, jq

I have a file in a subset of YAML with data such as the below:

```
# This is a comment
# This is another comment


spark:spark.ui.enabled: 'false'
spark:spark.sql.adaptive.enabled: 'true'
yarn:yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds: '259200'
```

I need to convert that into a JSON document looking like this (note that strings containing booleans and integers still remain strings):

```
{
  "spark:spark.ui.enabled": "false",
  "spark:spark.sql.adaptive.enabled": "true",
  "yarn:yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds", "259200"
}
```

The closest I got was this:

```
cat << EOF > ./file.yaml
> # This is a comment
> # This is another comment
> 
> 
> spark:spark.ui.enabled: 'false'
> spark:spark.sql.adaptive.enabled: 'true'
> yarn:yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds: '259200'
> EOF
echo {$(cat file.yaml | grep -o '^[^#]*' | sed '/^$/d' | awk -F": " '{sub($1, "\"&\""); print}' | paste -sd "," -  )}
```

which apart from looking rather gnarly doesn't give the correct answer, it returns:

```
{"spark:spark.ui.enabled": 'false',"spark:spark.sql.adaptive.enabled": 'true',"dataproc:dataproc.monitoring.stackdriver.enable": 'true',"spark:spark.submit.deployMode": 'cluster'}
```

which, if I pipe to `jq` causes a parse error.

I'm hoping I'm missing a much much easier way of doing this but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: forgive my naivety, I think of those tools as being part of bash, happy to be corrected. I am limited by the tools available to me in the docker image in which I'm running this, that image is built from a debian base.

Comment: Build a new docker image that includes the tools you need to work with YAML and JSON.

Comment: I do just want to deal with that specific input, perhaps the mention of yaml was a bum steer. I do have `jq` available

Comment: there are integers too. I have edited the sample above to reflect that

Comment: If you're used to `jq` then there's also a wrapper for it called `yq` that handles YAML: https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: ah very good to know. Unfortunately `yq` isnt available to me, this docker image is provided by another team in my org and I don't have any control over what is in it

Comment: `jq --version` returns `jq-1.5`. I need everything to be returned as string literals (so they should be wrapped in quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented in pure `jq` (tested with version 1.6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jq_script=$(cat <<'EOF'
def content_for_line:
  "^[[:space:]]*([#]|$)" as $ignore_re |           # regex for comments, blank lines
  "^(?<key>.*): (?<value>.*)$" as $content_re |    # regex for actual k/v pairs
  "^'(?<value>.*)'$" as $quoted_re |               # regex for values in single quotes
  if test($ignore_re) then {} else                 # empty lines add nothing to the data
    if test($content_re) then (                    # non-empty: match against $content_re
      capture($content_re) as $content |           # ...and put the groups into $content
      $content.key as $key |                       # string before ": " becomes $key
      (if ($content.value | test($quoted_re)) then # if value contains literal quotes...
         ($content.value | capture($quoted_re)).value # ...take string from inside quotes
       else
         $content.value                               # no quotes to strip
       end) as $value |                     # result of the above block becomes $value
      {"\($key)": "\($value)"}              # and return a map from one key to one value
    ) else
      # we get here if a line didn't match $ignore_re *or* $content_re
      error("Line \(.) is not recognized as a comment, empty, or valid content")
    end
  end;

# iterate over our input lines, passing each one to content_for_line and merging the result
# into the object we're building, which we eventually return as our result.
reduce inputs as $item ({}; . + ($item | content_for_line))
EOF
)

# jq -R: read input as raw strings
# jq -n: don't read from stdin until requested with "input" or "inputs"
jq -Rn "$jq_script" <file.yaml >file.json
```

Unlike syntax-unaware tools, this can *never* generate output that isn't valid JSON; and it can easily be extended with application-specific logic (f/e, to emit some values but not others as numeric literals rather than string literals) by adding an additional filter stage to inspect and modify the output of `content_for_line`.

Comment: oh my word, I don't know how that worked, but it did. Thank you so much Charles. I shall now spend the rest of the day pouring over it and trying to understand it :) thx again

Comment: (Also, I just tested it with my my real-world yaml document that is much larger than the sample I posted here and it worked great)

Comment: Just added some comments; hopefully they make it easier to follow. Let me know if there are other places clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a no-frills but simple solution:

```
def tidy: sub("^ *'?";"") | sub(" *'?$";"");
def kv: split(":") | [ (.[:-1] | join(":")), (.[-1]|tidy)];

reduce (inputs| select( test("^ *#|^ *$")|not) | kv) as $row ({};
    .[$row[0]] = $row[1] )
```

#### Invocation

```
jq -n -R -f tojson.jq input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in `awk` using `gsub` and `sprintf`, for example:

**(edit to add `","` separating json records)**

```
awk 'BEGIN {ol=0; print "{" } 
/^[^#]/ { 
    if (ol) print ","
    gsub ("\047", "\042")
    $1 = sprintf ("  \"%s\":", substr ($1, 1, length ($1) - 1))
    printf "%s %s", $1, $2
    ol++ 
} 
END { print "\n}" }' file.yaml
```

(**note:** though `jq` is the proper tool for json formatting)

**Explanation**

- `awk 'BEGIN { ol=0; print "{" }` call `awk` setting the *output line* variable `ol=0` for `","` output control and printing the header `"{"`,
- `/^[^#]/ {` only match non-comment lines,
- `if (ol) print ","` if the output line `ol` is greater than zero, output a trailing `","`
- `gsub ("\047", "\042")` replace all single-quotes with double-quotes,
- `$1 = sprintf ("  \"%s\":", substr ($1, 1, length ($1) - 1))` add 2 leading spaces and double-quotes around the first field (except for the last character) and then append a `':'` at the end.
- `print $1, $2` output the reformatted fields,
- `ol++` increment the output line count, and
- `END { print "}" }'` close by printing the `"}"` footer

**Example Use/Output**

Just select/paste the `awk` command above (changing the filename as needed)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {ol=0; print "{" }
> /^[^#]/ {
>     if (ol) print ","
>     gsub ("\047", "\042")
>     $1 = sprintf ("  \"%s\":", substr ($1, 1, length ($1) - 1))
>     printf "%s %s", $1, $2
>     ol++
> }
> END { print "\n}" }' file.yaml
{
  "spark:spark.ui.enabled": "false",
  "spark:spark.sql.adaptive.enabled": "true"
}
```

Comment: thanks David, that's close, but it doesn't place a comma after the first element thus not valid JSON